# Does my app need verification for using Gmail API?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm developing an application that shows to users their Gmail inbox and they can read, delete and send messages from within the app. I've read the Gmail API docs and have read their restricted scopes docs, but I also came across a part where it says that the application will need to be verified by Google.

Could anyone provide some advice/articles where the process is documented and whether the app will really need verification?
The verification itself is fine, but it does come at a pretty big price ($25k+).

Answer (score 1):

An app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, must go though the Google verification process.

The following is a list of Gmail [scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) and and there security level

[image: For the most part]

As you can see https://mail.google.com/ is a restricted scope which will mean that yes your application will need to go through the verification process.

To my knowledge the verification process is between ($25k - $75k) this is paid to a third party company which is responsible for the security check on your application. As you are requesting full access i would prepare for this to be on the higher end of the pricing curve.

Tip: If you intend to go through with it i recommend that you start early as it can take months.

Comment: I also read that verification by Google's team is mandatory but for client-side use of the API, the security check can be skipped. As I don't have a need to store or see the user's emails, I can go with only the client-side use but I'm not sure if the above is true. Do you have any info about this?

Comment: Its mandatory for a lot os scopes.  I don't think client or server sided matters readly.  If its a gsuite application that's only accessible for users in the domain i think you can bypass with some of the scopes.  if you need to read, delete and send  then you are seeing the users emails. If your system does a message.get its yours your system has access to it thats what google is worried about.

Comment: But I won't get the message because as I said, the front-end will make a GET to get them. This is done from the client's browser and doesn't go through my server. Same goes for the POST requests.